# What's the proper way to overwrite system/hidden files with Windows API?

Tags: winapi, file-copying

When you copy files using **CopyFileExA** function (see [Windows API Reference: winbase.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexa)) it has the ability to "fail" or not, if the destination file already exist, using (or clearing) the flag COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS. However, I can not find the way to overwrite files with attributes Read Only, Hidden or System.

I am working on a backup program with specific requirements which I can't find anywhere else.

I was thinking that before copying a file with one or more of those attributes set, perhaps I could clear those attributes on an existing file and then proceed to copy the file, knowing that my program will overwrite existing file with clear attributes.

Is that the best approach?

Another option would be just delete the old file before copying a new one. But I'm afraid that if I delete the old (backup) file and only then will try to copy the new one AND if the copy for some reason fails, then I will ended up without a backup file.

Or maybe there's a way of overwriting System/Hidden files that I'm not aware of.

What would be the best method of accomplishing this - copy and overwriting files with System/Hidden/ReadOnly attributes set?

Comment: What if you ran the application with elevated privileges?

Comment: you must remove read only attribute first and in case System/Hidden too

Comment: You shouldn't be using an ANSI API when dealing with file names you do not control. If it fails the result is loss of information, probably not a design goal for backup software. It also sounds like you're planning to write into an existing backup directory. If the copy fails (say, if you're running out of disk space or quota) then the result is a lost file. A more robust solution would copy into a temporary directory (on the same volume), and once the full copy is in place, replace the existing backup folder with the temporary one. That operation can be made atomic.

Comment: @IInspectable : I do have control over files and this is for backing up files that has been modified on the web server, so I need to backup only individual files that has been changed. So your advice would be: 1) Copy file that needs to be backed to the destination drive under a temporary name. 2) Clear attributes of the old files in case it was R.O./Hid./Sys. 3) Delete this old file. 4) Move/rename the temporary file into destination folder under original name.

Is that the best approach?